# How can I get a message if a string does not exist?

Tags: c#, string

I'm attempting to read a text file and delete a user entered string. I cannot get it to report a message if the string does not exist.

I cannot explain everything I've tried to this point, it's been many things. I know there is nothing in it's current form that would give me the results I expect, but I've tried many many things and this is currently where it's at. For the code that is there, it's doing everything I'm telling it to do.

```
if (rButtonDelete.Checked)
        {
            bool isValid = txtID.Text.Length < 5;
            if (txtID.Text == "")
            {
                lbOne.Items.Add("You must enter a fixture to delete.");
            }
                else                    
            if(!isValid==false)
            {                    
                lbOne.Items.Add("Enter full fixture ID to delete.");
            }
            else                
            {
                var oldLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\09 Quality\CMM Fixtures\fixtures.txt");
                var newLines = oldLines.Where(lines => !lines.Contains(txtID.Text));
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"F:\09 Quality\CMM Fixtures\fixtures.txt", newLines);
                lbOne.Items.Add(txtID.Text + " was deleted.");
            }
        }
```

As stated above, as it exists now, it does everything I am telling it to do. I just need to report that a string being searched for does not exist if in doesn't. No matter what I type into the text box, it tells me it's been deleted, even if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Side-note: you really find `if(!isValid==false)` more readable than `if(isValid)`?

Comment: if(!isValid == false)  ?

Comment: `if(!isValid==false)`.. is this intentional?

Comment: double negations are not not hard to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
if (oldLines.Count() == newLines.Count())
{
    lbOne.Items.Add(txtID.Text + " does not exist.");
}
else
{
    lbOne.Items.Add(txtID.Text + " was deleted.");
}
```

Comment: Will work. But will also enumerate `oldLines.Where(...)` twice. Depending on the amount of data, it might be worthwile to improve.

Comment: @KlausGütter true, but only really a consideration if expecting very large files.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Of course, therefore I said "Depending on the amount of data"

Comment: This will be very small, maybe 1000-1200 lines. Currently there's only 350 lines. It's taken 30ish years to get that big! This is why I didn't use a database.

Is there any way, appending this file, to choose what order it rewrites as? Meaning, if for example I prefer to have it in chronological order by either the fixture number, or maybe by the rack it's on? Currently it's just in the order they're entered.